# abline will not put line in correct position

Tags: r

I am quite new to programming/R and I'm having a very unusual problem. I've made a scatterplot and I would like to simply put the x y axis at 0 on the plot. However, when I use abline they are slightly off. I managed to get them to 0 using trial and error, but trying to plot other lines becomes impossible.

```
library('car')
scatterplot(cost~qaly, reg.line=FALSE, smooth=FALSE, spread=FALSE, 
        boxplots='xy', span=0.5, xlab="QALY", ylab="COST", main="Bootstrap", 
        cex=0.5, data=scat2, xlim=c(-.05,.05), grid=FALSE)
abline(v = 0, h = 0)
```

This gives lines which are slightly to the left and below 0.

here is an image of what this returns:
(I can't post an image since I'm new apparently)

I found that these values put the lines on 0:

```
abline(v=0.003)
abline(h=3000)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Could you post some data and the obtained chart?

Comment: `require(car); set.seed(10); x <- rnorm(1000); y <- rnorm(1000); scatterplot(y ~ x); abline(v=0, h=0)` This should replicate it.

Comment: The `scatterplot` function is a custom plotting function from a specific package that does lots of extra stuff. By default it plots boxplots in the margins, but in order to do that it has to adjust the plot axes and place the labels in a customized way to make them appear correctly. This means that any naive attempt to plot on the "usual" coordinate system afterwards will not work. If you suppress the boxplots with `boxplots = FALSE`, you can add lines using the usual methods.

Comment: As I simply read the documentation, I easily found the argument `reset.par`, which will also solve your problem, presumably.

Comment: @joran is right, I swear I looked specifically for that parameter and missed it

Comment: @joran Thanks a lot the `reset.par` worked perfectly! I'll read more carefully next time. I also tried setting `boxplots = FALSE` but the graph got even more weird afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @Laterow's example, reproduce the issue

```
require(car)
set.seed(10)
x <- rnorm(1000); y <- rnorm(1000)
scatterplot(y ~ x)
abline(v=0, h=0)
```

[image]

`scatterplot` seems to be resetting the `par` settings on exit. You can sort of check this with `locator(1)` around some point, eg, for `{-3,-3}` I get

```
# $x
# [1] -2.469414
# 
# $y
# [1] -2.223922
```

#### Option 1

As @joran points out, `reset.par = FALSE` is the easiest way

```
scatterplot(y ~ x, reset.par = FALSE)
abline(v=0, h=0)
```

[image]

#### Option 2

In `?scatterplot`, it says that `...` is passed to `plot` meaning you can use `plot`'s very useful `panel.first` and `panel.last` arguments (among others).

```
scatterplot(y ~ x, panel.first = {grid(); abline(v = 0)}, grid = FALSE)
```

[image]

Note that if you were to do the basic

```
scatterplot(y ~ x, panel.first = abline(v = 0))
```

you would be unable to see the line because the default `scatterplot` `grid` covers it up, so you can turn that off, plot a `grid` *first* then do the `abline`.

You could also do the `abline` in `panel.last`, but this would be on top of your points, so maybe not as desirable.

Comment: Hey hey, sorry for the slow reply! the reset.par method worked like a charm.

Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my questions!

Comment: I read the documentation for `reset.par`, but I don't completely understand what it does.

_if TRUE then plotting parameters are reset to their previous values when scatterplot exits; if FALSE then the mar and mfcol parameters are altered for the current plotting device. Set to FALSE if you want to add graphical elements (such as lines) to the plot._ Am I risking any inaccuracy in the plot by doing this?

Comment: @ChrisBrown no you'll be fine. `scatterplot` takes a snapshot of `par()` when called and resets to those settings when it finishes. During `scatterplot`, it uses its own `mar`gins and `mfcol` so they wont have to be supplied by the user. if you set to false, all the `par` options set by `scatterplot` will replace the default or any that you have set which is useful if you need to add things after scatterplot finishes--you will need the current coordinates not the previous ones which is what happened to you

Comment: Ok perfect! Thanks a lot. This was a very productive first stack overflow experience.